# mySQL: Issue with Left Join

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT c.`entity_id`,c. p.`name` as parent_id, c.`name`
  FROM category c
  LEFT JOIN category p WHERE c.`parent_id = p.id
  WHERE c.is_active = 1
  ORDER BY c.parent_id ASC, c.position ASC;
```

But I get an error on the first WHERE clause, can anyone spot the error here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added `where` clause twice. Try as below :

```
SELECT c.`entity_id`,c. p.`name` as parent_id, c.`name`
FROM category c
  LEFT JOIN category p on c.`parent_id = p.id
  Where c.is_active = 1
  ORDER BY c.parent_id ASC, c.position ASC;
```